# getting syntax error at line 34 : `<<' unmatched in ksh script

Tags: shell, sqlplus, ksh

I have a shell script, when I execute it, I get the error

```
syntax error at line 34 : `<<' unmatched in ksh script

column_name=`sqlplus -s $BASE_DB_CONN<<!!
    WHENEVER SQLERROR exit ROLLBACK
    set SQLPROMPT ''
    set heading off
    set pagesize 1000
    set linesize 5000
    set feedback off
    set define on
    set verify off
    @smm9_stream_map.sql $STREAM_NAME $FIELD_NAME"
    exit
    !!`;
```

To my surprise the same thing works in the while loop  altered script as below

```
while [ $a -lt ${NO_LOOP} ]
do
column_name=`sqlplus -s $BASE_DB_CONN<<!!
    WHENEVER SQLERROR exit ROLLBACK
    set SQLPROMPT ''
    set heading off
    set pagesize 1000
    set linesize 5000
    set feedback off
    set define on
    set verify off
    @smm9_stream_map.sql $STREAM_NAME $FIELD_NAME"
    exit
    !!`;
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Why does the second script work but not the first one?

Comment: Three things spring to mind: 1) Don't use backticks.  Use the $(...) notation. 2) Use something else as the here-doc terminator.  Exclamation marks are special characters in many circumstances and are prone to be misinterpreted. 3) and probably more relevant to your question, the terminator must not be indented.  Make sure it starts in column 1.

Answer (score 3):

The heredoc terminator must be the **only** text on that line, no other whitespace allowed (*)

```
column_name=$(sqlplus -s $BASE_DB_CONN<<!!
    ....
    exit
!!
)
```

(*) the exception being, for heredocs using `<<-`, any leading **tabs** will be stripped from the heredoc, including from the terminator. I see in my ksh93 man page:

> If **#** is appended to <<, then leading spaces and tabs will  be
>                        stripped  off  the  first  line  of  the  document  and up to an equivalent indentation will be
>                        stripped from the remaining lines and from *word*.