# Why am I getting `(' unmatched

Tags: unix, ksh

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting the error defined in the title.

The other day I was having the same trouble in a similar script but with `<<' unmatched. I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186743/getting-syntax-error-at-line-34-unmatched-in-ksh-script) which helped me solve my problem. I am having trouble applying the same sort of fix to this issue.

My block:

```
   +95          master_table=$(sqlplus -s <<- EOF
   +96          ${SQLMSTR}
   +97          select * from UTILS.PAGE_TO;
   +98          EOF
   +99          )
```

I can get it to work if I remove all whitespace before `EOF` on line `98`. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

I'm using ksh93

My "other" block from a separate script that works (there is whitespace before each line on script):

```
sqlplus -s <<- EOF
${SQLMSTR}
exec utils.change_page('${TEAM}');
EOF
```

Comment: Are you using tabs for indentation? `<<-` works with tabs only, not spaces.

Comment: Hi, @codeforester, I am using spaces, however I also tried using `<<#` with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<<-` to `<<` and shift `EOF` to the beginning of the line:

```
   +95          master_table=$(sqlplus -s << EOF
   +96          ${SQLMSTR}
   +97          select * from UTILS.PAGE_TO;
   +98  EOF
   +99          )
```

I know it looks ugly.  One way to work around this is to create a function that takes the SQL statement as an argument and runs it.  Like this:

```
function run_sqlplus() {
  sqlplus -s << EOF
    ${SQLMSTR}
    $@
EOF
}

    : indented code
    master_table=$(run_sqlplus 'select * from UTILS.PAGE_TO;')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. As I stated in my question, I was able to run with success if I moved `EOF` to the beginning of line `98`, as suggested in your answer, however, I would like to keep the formatting consistent. Is it not possible for me to do so?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a suggestion for how to keep the indentation.

Comment: thank you, I did use the function method in another script, I just thought there was another way through using a here-doc